# NSTextField word wrap

Tags: objective-c, macos, word-wrap, nstextfield, nstextfieldcell

I have NSTextField containing a long string, I would like the string to be split in several lines.
But now if I limit the length of the view I see the string clipped.
I have tried also to use cell's setWraps method and setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping but the problem is still there

What can I try? I am working on mac OS application (not Iphone)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Finally I was able to fix this problem. Solution was quite simple.
Modifying the nib file by changing

```
 <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMinY="YES"/>
```

by

```
 <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" />
```

And giving the textfield the desired width

Answer (score -1):

Are you calling setWraps: after the text field is in focus? The field editor would be the one getting in the way. If you resign the first responder first, then it should work:

```
[window makeFirstResponder:nil];
[[textField cell] setWraps:YES];
```

Comment: I have tried that and it does not work. When should I call the setWraps? Now i am calling it in the init method, but the text is set after.

Comment: I am using a nib file to create the view and I am initialising it and adding the text in NSViewController class. Am I missing something?